There is no webpack in my project but I get webpack error

React project doesn't have webpack directly but umijs does, probably umijs is using webpack.
I get this kind of errors when I install a new package in the project.
This time it gives this error for the sunflower-antd package.
I can't really think of what I can do. What's your advice?

Are you using a framework like Vite or Next.js?

Protip, but also explicitly in the posting guidelines: do not show pictures of text. Copy-paste, or type the text in your post.
